# npm -g install modules in a npm folder in my home folder on Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, npm, osx-mavericks

On npm docs it says that npm will install global modules inside /usr/local/lib/node_modules and drop executable files on /usr/local/bin, but when I do "npm install -g module" it creates a new npm folder in my home folder with a bin and lib folder inside and the global module is installed there.

How can I change this behaviour and install global module on /usr/local/ ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/faq.html) website

> **Where does npm put stuff? See npm-folders(5)**
>
> tl;dr:
>
> Use the npm root command to see where modules go, and the npm bin
>   command to see where executables go Global installs are different from
>   local installs. If you install something with the -g flag, then its
>   executables go in npm bin -g and its modules go in npm root -g.

**Edit:**

All information about local and global installation can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html). I believe for global installation you will need root access.

Comment: `npm bin -g` prints `Users/MyUser/npm/bin`. How can I change that path?